# MVC FilterEditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to have a filter row in my cshtml list where I can use the editor for the column.
I want text editors for string fields, dropdown editors for fields with foreign key constraints, date editors for date fields.

My auto-generated model below.

```
public partial class MEMBER
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Title")]
    public string TITLE { get; set; }
    public string FIRST_NAME { get; set; }
    public string MIDDLE_NAME { get; set; }
    public string LAST_NAME { get; set; }
    public string SUFFIX { get; set; }
    public string EMAIL { get; set; }
    public string PHONE { get; set; }
    public string EXT { get; set; }
    public string FAX { get; set; }
    public string STATE { get; set; }
    public string PARTY { get; set; }
    public string DISTRICT { get; set; }
    public string ACTIVE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ACTIVATED_DT { get; set; }
    public string ACTIVATED_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DEACTIVATED_DT { get; set; }
    public string DEACTIVATED_ID { get; set; }
    public string ROOM { get; set; }
    public string MOST_ACTIVE_ISSUES { get; set; }
    public string NOAA_NEXT_GEN { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> REELECTION { get; set; }
    public string COMMENTS { get; set; }
    public string MEMBER_DISTINCTION { get; set; }
    public string FLAG_TYPE { get; set; }
    public string CURR_STATUS { get; set; }

    public virtual US_STATE US_STATE { get; set; }
}
```

In the Razor view I would have the following...

```
@Html.FilterEditorFor(model => model.US_STATE.STATE_NAME)
```

And in my custom helpers, I would have something like this.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString FilterEditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
    )
    {
        MvcHtmlString result = new MvcHtmlString("");
        // return MvcHtmlString.Create(TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(html, html.ViewData.ModelMetadata, String.Empty, null /* templateName */, DataBoundControlMode.Edit, null /* additionalViewData */));
        ModelMetadata mm = html.ViewData.ModelMetadata;
        string s = "";
        switch (mm.DataTypeName)
        {
            case "DateTime":
                s = "<input id='{0}' class='xgFilterDate' type='text'>";
                break;
            case "bool":
                s = "<input id='{0}' class='xgFilterDate' type='checkbox'>";
                break;
            case "string":
                s = "<input id='{0}' class='xgFilterText' type='text'>";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        s = string.Format(s, mm.ModelType.Name + "_" + mm.ShortDisplayName);
        return new MvcHtmlString(s);
    }
```

I can't seem to get the custom helper to work right.  Anyone have an idea?

Comment: In what way doesn't it "work right"?

Comment: The mm.DataTypeName is always null.